# Creating week variable in pandas with custom start day for week

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe indexed to a Time_Stamp:

```
df = DataFrame(index = pd.date_range('4/1/2017', freq='3D', periods=10))
df['weekday'] = df.index.weekday_name
```

Data looks like this:

```
              weekday
2017-04-01   Saturday
2017-04-04    Tuesday
2017-04-07     Friday
2017-04-10     Monday
2017-04-13   Thursday
2017-04-16     Sunday
2017-04-19  Wednesday
2017-04-22   Saturday
2017-04-25    Tuesday
2017-04-28     Friday
```

I want to create a new column 'week' that will give the week ordinal of the year but with a weekday.

I know I can just do this:

```
df['week_sun'] = df.index.week
```

Except I want the first day of the week to be something besides Sunday. For this question, lets say I need it to be Wednesday so that the resulting dataframe would be like so:

```
              weekday  week_sun  week_wed
2017-04-01   Saturday        13        13
2017-04-04    Tuesday        14        13
2017-04-07     Friday        14        14
2017-04-10     Monday        15        14
2017-04-13   Thursday        15        15
2017-04-16     Sunday        15        15
2017-04-19  Wednesday        16        16
2017-04-22   Saturday        16        16
2017-04-25    Tuesday        17        16
2017-04-28     Friday        17        17
```

I'm at a loss to how to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explane more detailled what you want to achieve with the week_wed column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your requirements, you would only need to subtract 1 to the week number, in case the day of the week is "before" the reference day (Wednesday in your example).

```
In [162]: df
Out[162]: 
              weekday  week_sun
2017-04-01   Saturday        13
2017-04-04    Tuesday        14
2017-04-07     Friday        14
2017-04-10     Monday        15
2017-04-13   Thursday        15
2017-04-16     Sunday        15
2017-04-19  Wednesday        16
2017-04-22   Saturday        16
2017-04-25    Tuesday        17
2017-04-28     Friday        17

In [163]: df['week_wed'] = df['week_sun']
```

Let's now shift the value where needed, meaning when the weekday is before Wednesday, hence `df.index.dayofweek < 2`.

```
In [164]: df.loc[df.index.dayofweek < 2, 'week_wed'] = (df[df.index.dayofweek < 2]['week_sun'] - 2) % 52 + 1

In [165]: df
Out[165]: 
              weekday  week_sun  week_wed
2017-04-01   Saturday        13        13
2017-04-04    Tuesday        14        13
2017-04-07     Friday        14        14
2017-04-10     Monday        15        14
2017-04-13   Thursday        15        15
2017-04-16     Sunday        15        15
2017-04-19  Wednesday        16        16
2017-04-22   Saturday        16        16
2017-04-25    Tuesday        17        16
2017-04-28     Friday        17        17
```

I didn't exactly subtract 1, but instead used a modulo operation (`(X-2) %52 +1)`) so I can convert week 1 to week 52 from the previous year if need be:

```
              weekday  week_sun  week_wed
2017-12-27  Wednesday        52        52
2017-12-30   Saturday        52        52
2018-01-02    Tuesday         1        52
2018-01-05     Friday         1         1
```